# How to use .Net DLL in Uno Platform WASM?

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, uno, dynamic-dll-import

I'd wrote a DLL in .net.
I use it in UNO Platform for UWP. Now i'd like tu use some function of this DLL in WASM project.
Is it Possible ?
In UWP i connect the DLL in reference folder.
In WASM how can i done ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your .NET project file has references to UNO WASM bootstrap packages. If not add them like [this](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/blob/main/doc/using-the-bootstrapper.md#how-to-use-the-bootstrapper-with-net-5-and-later).

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer" Version="2.1.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Once this is done and your .NET project is able to build and run as  WASM. There should a bunch of files generated by UNO Bootstrap WASM in the `/bin` folder of .NET project. Some of those include

1. `uno_bootstrap.js`
2. `dotnet.js`
3. `dotnet.wasm`

Look at JS code in first two, `uno-bootstrap.js` is the entry point, which will call `dotnet.js` which will have JS bindings into WASM. This will also list any DLLs that are linked into WASM. YOu can add your DLL here.